# how to do framing for audio signal in java

Tags: java, audio, wav

I want to split my audio file (.wav format) in frames of 32 milliseconds each. Sampling frequency - 16khz, number of channels - 1(mono), pcm signal, sample size = 93638.

After getting the data in the byte format, I am converting the `byte array` storing the wav file data to `double array` since I require it to pass it to a method which accepts a double array, I am using the following code can someone tell me how to proceed?

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class AudioFiles
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String file = "D:/p.wav";
    AudioFiles afiles = new AudioFiles();
    byte[] data1 = afiles.readAudioFileData(file);
    byte[] data2 = afiles.readWAVAudioFileData(file);
    System.out.format("data len1: %d\n", data1.length);
    System.out.format("data len2: %d\n", data2.length);

    /* for(int i=0;i<data2.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.format("\t"+data2[i]);

    }*/
    System.out.println();

    /* for(int j=0;j<data1.length;j++)
    {
    System.out.format("\t"+data1[j]);

    }*/
    System.out.format("diff len: %d\n", data2.length - data1.length);

    double[] d = new double[data1.length];
    d = toDoubleArray(data1);
    for (int j = 0; j < data1.length; j++)
    {
      System.out.format("\t" + d[j]);

    }

    daub a = new daub();
    a.daubTrans(d);
  }

  public static double[] toDoubleArray(byte[] byteArray)
  {
    int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    double[] doubles = new double[byteArray.length / times];
    for (int i = 0; i < doubles.length; i++)
    {
      doubles[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray, i * times, times).getDouble();
    }
    return doubles;
  }

  public byte[] readAudioFileData(final String filePath)
  {
    byte[] data = null;
    try
    {
      final ByteArrayOutputStream baout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      final File file = new File(filePath);
      final AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem
        .getAudioInputStream(file);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
      int c;
      while ((c = audioInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
      {
        baout.write(buffer, 0, c);
      }

      audioInputStream.close();
      baout.close();
      data = baout.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
  }

  public byte[] readWAVAudioFileData(final String filePath)
  {
    byte[] data = null;
    try
    {
      final ByteArrayOutputStream baout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      final AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath));

      AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, baout);
      audioInputStream.close();
      baout.close();
      data = baout.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

I want to pass the `double array d` to method performing wavelet transform, in the frames of 32 millisecond  since it accepts a double array.

In my previous question I was given a reply that:
**At 16kHz sample rate you'll have 16 samples per millisecond. Therefore, each 32ms frame would be 32*16=512 mono samples. Multiply by the number of bytes-per-sample (typically 2 or 4) and that will be the number of bytes per frame.**

I want to know whether my frame size changes when I convert my array from byte format to double format or does it remains the same??

My [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389143/how-to-do-framing-for-a-given-wave-file-in-java).

Comment: What unit is your sample size? 93638 sounds quite large.

Comment: @pietu1998 sample size is of type integer integer ,a 2 second wav audio file

Comment: I mean, is 93638 the number of samples, some time, or what? Sample size usually refers to the amount of bits used to store one sample.

Comment: @Pietu1998 bits per sample is 16 or 2bytes